# How do I solve green layer problem while playing HEVC in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: video, vlc, codecs, hevc

I have a HEVC (x.265) video. I am trying to play it in latest VLC (`Rincewind 2.1.6`) in Ubuntu 14.04. I have already installed VLC plugin for HEVC. Here is the screenshot:
[image]

However, when I try to play video, a green layer is coming over the video. Here's a screenshot:
[image]

I tried with lots of other players like DragonPlayer, SMPlayer. All of these have problems. So, I suppose this is a problem with Ubuntu itself. Any solution?

**Update:** I updated to 2.2.1 . Still, the problem persists.

Comment: Reproduced on Trusty with VLC 2.2.1 with vlc-plugin-libde265 0.1.6-1ppa1~trusty1.1. However, I can play the file with MPlayer SVN-r37401.

Comment: Updated VLC, but still problem exists.

Comment: Does it happen for every hevc video or only one ?

Comment: Only some of the videos. Not to all!

Comment: What video driver are you using  ? Are you using hardware decoding with VDPAU ?

Comment: If possible provide a link to a sample vid that doesn't work right. Can you play back any of the samples from here? - http://www.libde265.org/downloads-videos/

Comment: @solsTiCe It's Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller

Comment: @doug both of those videos are being played fine in my machine.

Comment: you could install mpv from here & try. It supports hevc without the need for any plugins, if still green then without a sample can't say if there is a solution - https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/ubuntu/mpv-tests

Comment: I have the same issue on 14.04 with the libde265 plugin and vlc 2.1.6

media info: BPS : 127857 _STATISTICS_TAGS : BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP : mkvmerge v7.8.0 ('River Man') 64bit built on Mar 27 2015 16:31:37 Codec: MPEG-H Part2/HEVC (H.265) (hevc) Resolution: 720x288 Display resolution: 720x288 Decoded format: Planar 4:2:0 YUV

Answer (score 1):

Before I begin.
Stay away from VLC whatever VLC since I'm an avid reader and writer and I've read a lot about it. Even VLC says that they're not the best player out there and when comes to problems and they've posted a lot saying that they are trying to make the most compatible player possible. So it's not the best. You can argue.

***1st possibility*** -
*During the same problems as yours*. ***I've changed to DivX player because I discovered DivX uses a different plugin and the video was DivX made*** and *every different player use his own plugins* for HEVC and libde265.

***2nd possibility*** -
Hardware compatibility. *Try another computer instead* and with recent graphic adapters like NVIDIA or AMD.

***3rd possibility*** -
Play the video on Linux if you're using Windows and vice versa if you're using Linux.

I'd easily resolved the same problems as yours years ago like green screens, lines on the screen, video playing with lags, and videos not playing at all. All by using those methods above.

Hope it helps!

***Edit:*** Changing to a recent graphics adapter that may or not resolve your problem same as trying to play *HVEC* on *Android* *devices*. Because of a lot of hardware compatibility issues, developers are trying to make it possible!

- **Non-related (only for android)** ***external links***:
  [Is there any Video Player for android that can play HEVC videos smoothly?](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-any-Video-Player-for-android-that-can-play-HEVC-videos-smoothly)
  [How to Enjoy HEVC/ H.265 Video Playback on Android](https://www.droidviews.com/enjoy-hevc-h-265-video-playback-on-android/)
  [Much Ado About Not Much (HEVC Support in Android)](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/much-ado-hevc-support-android-jan-ozer) ~ *May 23, 2018,*
  [Supported media formats](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats) ~ *android official*

Answer (score -1):

Try restarting the window manager and then rebooting your computer.

1. Close everything.
2. Switch to a tty other than the default one with the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F#</kbd>, replacing <kbd>F#</kbd> with any function key (keys <kbd>F1</kbd> through <kbd>F12</kbd>) other than the one that displays your usual Ubuntu login/home screen.
3. If a login screen is prompted, enter your username (the one you typically see above the password field when you log in and in the terminal before the `@` symbol; It should have no capital letters, spaces, or symbols), then your password.
4. Run the following command: `sudo service lightdm restart`
5. Wait for the command to complete and go back to the default tty by using the shortcut mentioned in step 2 and cycling through function keys until you reach the vanilla Ubuntu home screen.
6. Reboot your computer.

Things should be fine and dandy when you log back in.

Answer (score -3):

You have to install **libde265** via PPA. To install open Terminal and run the commands below:

`sudo apt-add-repository ppa:strukturag/libde265 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install vlc-plugin-libde265`

Comment: I have already done that as the first screenshot says.